# How to display legal link on registration page in colorbox node?

Tags: javascript

I have installed the module [Legal](https://www.drupal.org/project/legal) and choose to have a checkbox on registration. On registration of a new user is then displayed:

- Accept Terms & Conditions of Use *

The Terms & Conditions are link to page `/legal` in the same window.

I want to show this link in colorbox node so a style should be appended. Probably I have to modify the code (which I do not prefer) or can implement a hook for this? If so, how?

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the class `colorbox` to the Terms and Conditions link generated by the Legal module.

This is easily setup through a `theme_` function override.
Use the following code in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
    function YOUR_THEME_legal_accept_label($variables) {
      if ($variables['link']) {
        return t('<strong>Accept</strong> <a class="colorbox" href="@terms">Terms & Conditions</a> of Use', array('@terms' => url('legal')));
      }
      else {
        return t('<strong>Accept</strong> Terms & Conditions of Use');
      }
    }
```

Note: you might have to tweak the output in the popup, but that's outside of the scope I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like `class="colorbox"` is a variation of adding `target="_blank"`.

So as an alternative to modifying your theme's template.php file (as in the previous answer), you may want to use some of the suggestions in [issue #372721 on D.O.](https://www.drupal.org/node/372721) I.e.:

- via a **form alter**, similar to what is  explained in [comment #27](https://www.drupal.org/node/372721#comment-8519855).
- using **jQuery**, similar to what is explained in [comment #24](https://www.drupal.org/node/372721#comment-6977610).